# Как уменьшить размер python файла при компилированиии через PyInstaller?

Tags: pyinstaller, exe

У меня есть простой код IP-grabber'а (не подумайте ничего плохого), всего в 21(!!) строчку. Скомпилировав его через PyInstaller используя только параметр --onefile у меня вышло.. 18 мб ярости. Как можно его уменьшить (по размеру конечно), потому-что в моем представлении размер должен быть не более 5мб.
P.S. В коде есть импорты: aiogram(bot, types), asynco, requests(get), socket.

Comment: Интерпретатор Питона не маленький.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629486/how-can-i-create-the-minimum-size-executable-with-pyinstaller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В исполняемый exe `PyInstaller` включается интерпретатор `Python`, все его зависимости, ваш код, код модулей, поэтому говорить про 5мб нецелесообразно.

1. Если вы не использовали сжатие `upx`, то обязательно [используйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1529633/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-exe-python-kivy).
2. Также стоит изменить параметр `strip` в spec файле вашего приложения на `True`.
3. Исключите модули которые не должны входить в вашу итоговую сборку (параметр `excludes`).